# How to run WAF compiled C++ program from within test script?

Tags: python, c++, testing, waf

Dear WAF build system experts,

Let's suppose that you use the WAF build system to build a library `fooLib` and a program `fooProg`.  Then, you want to check the program `fooProg` by a Python script `fooProgTest` that checks the output of `fooProg`.

Here is an minimum example for `fooLib` and `fooProg`:

```
$ cat fooLib/fooLib.cpp 
int foo()
{
    return 42;
}
```

```
$ cat fooProg/fooProg.cpp 
#include <iostream>

extern int foo();

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In this example,  it is my goal to to have a Python script that checks that `fooProg` outputs 42.
Here comes my not so clean solution:

```
import os
from waflib.Tools import waf_unit_test


def options(opt):
    opt.load("compiler_cxx waf_unit_test python")


def configure(cnf):
    cnf.load("compiler_cxx waf_unit_test python")

def build(bld):
    bld.add_post_fun(waf_unit_test.summary)
    bld.options.clear_failed_tests= True

    bld(features= "cxx cxxshlib",
        target= "fooLib",
        source= "fooLib/fooLib.cpp")

    bld(features= "cxx cxxprogram",
        target= "fooProg/fooProg",
        source= "fooProg/fooProg.cpp",
        use= "fooLib")

    testEnv= os.environ.copy()
    testEnv["FOO_EXE"]= bld.path.find_or_declare("fooProg/fooProg").abspath()
    bld(features= "test_scripts",
        test_scripts_source= "fooProgTest/fooProgTest.py",
        test_scripts_template= "${PYTHON} ${SRC[0].abspath()}",
        test_scripts_paths= {
            "LD_LIBRARY_PATH": bld.bldnode.abspath()
        },
        test_scripts_env= testEnv
       )
```

```
cat fooProgTest/fooProgTest.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import subprocess

assert subprocess.check_output("{}".format(
        os.environ["FOO_EXE"])).startswith("42")
```

My questions are below:

- Does anyone of you know how to avoid setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH manually?
- How to avoid setting the path of `fooProg` via the environment variable "FOO_EXE"?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone of you know how to avoid setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH manually?

You can specify the runtime search path for your executable. Assuming that the file `fooLib.so` is in the same directory as `fooProg`, the following change to your wscript should suffice:

```py
    bld(features= "cxx cxxprogram",
        target= "fooProg/fooProg",
        source= "fooProg/fooProg.cpp",
        use= "fooLib",
        rpath= "$ORIGIN")
```

Which makes LD to take the directory, where the executable is stored, also into consideration, when searching for shared objects.

> How to avoid setting the path of fooProg via the environment variable "FOO_EXE"?

With `subprocess.check_output` you can pass multiple arguments. I.e.

```py
    subprocess.check_output([
        "your_executable_to_launch",
        "arg1",
        "arg2"
    ])
```

In your test script you would have to read the arguments either using `sys.argv` or `argparse`.

---

**Extra**:

Launching the interpreter to launch to launch your application seems a bit hacky. Instead, define a custom task (implement `waflib.Task.Task`), which then runs `subprocess.check_output`<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> AFAIK waf gives you a convenient method to launch processes, although I cannot remember its name.